# returned nil from -traitCollection, which is not allowed in Xcode 11 Beta

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Assertion failure in UITraitCollection * _Nonnull
returned nil from -traitCollection, which is not allowed?
when I try to run Xcode 11 beta in ios 13 it crashed. I don't know what was wrong.

Comment: you need to add some code. From what I gather, you are maybe trying to modify a constraint's value but the IBOutlet against the same is not created or not connected.

Comment: now I got a solution by add some code DispatchQueue.main.asyn{ //code } after featch Data

Comment: Good to know. Glad you worked that out :)

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you post a detailed answer?

Comment: I try to debug the class that crashed and put DispatchQueue.main.asyn{ //code } on method or statement of code that I'm Suspected​​ it will crashed one by one so the problem was solved.

Comment: example//--Add pull to refresh DispatchQueue.main.async{self.myTableview.addSubview(self.refreshControl)}

Comment: Same issue here, I have this assert in one of my tests when trying to initialise a UIActivityIndicatorView in the main thread...

Answer (score 12):

## [super init]

I ran across this problem because one of the unnamed previous coders on my codebase, whom I frequently curse, didn't call `[super init]` on a class that implements the `UITraitEnvironment` (aka `UIView` or `UIViewController`)!

If I could wield a battle hammer backwards five years in time, I would.

This implementation in a subclass of `UIViewController`…

```
- (id)initWithStartPositionPdf:(float)startPosition withScrollViewHeight:(float)scrollViewHeight {
    _startPosition = startPosition;
    _scrollViewHeight = scrollViewHeight;

    self.isPdfView = YES;

    return self;
}
```

was updated to…

```
- (instancetype)initWithStartPositionPdf:(float)startPosition withScrollViewHeight:(float)scrollViewHeight {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    _startPosition = startPosition;
    _scrollViewHeight = scrollViewHeight;
    _isPdfView = YES;
    return self;
}
```

and resolved the crash I started receiving in Xcode 11 / iOS 13.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. And also updating an app written by someone else...

Comment: Id upvote this a million times if I could. I spent many hours trying to figure this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is how iOS 13 and Xcode 11 deal with the main thread checker inconsistencies.

basically, you are updating the UI from a background thread. Just make sure you're updating all your UI in the main thread.

Simply wrap the code that updates your UI inside `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`.

Answer (score 1):

**Just simple put your code in main thread of UI update :**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
             {
          // Put your code here 
           }
```