# Application crashes on iOS 13 because of returned nil from -traitCollection, which is not allowed

Tags: ios, objective-c, telegram, ios13

I am working on Telegram source code from the [archived repo](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram) and application crashes in every ViewController and I can see the following error. I also tried to comment out some codes but the crash just moves from one class to another. Is there any way to stop `traitCollection` from causing these crashes?

```
Telegram[50090:787790] *** Assertion failure in UITraitCollection * _Nonnull _UIGetCurrentFallbackTraitCollection(void)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3899.13.13/_UIFallbackEnvironment.m:91
Telegram[50090:787790] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<Decorated498f14ad: 0x7f80e9d46b20; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 0; 8 14); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000023abc00>> returned nil from -traitCollection, which is not allowed.'
```

PS: I cannot switch to newer versions of Telegram iOS.

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949568/returned-nil-from-traitcollection-which-is-not-allowed-in-xcode-11-beta) but it didn't help

Also I tried to run my lines of code using a async dispatcher but still no change

```
First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b98bde __exceptionPreprocess + 350
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff503b5b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b98958 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff255eb7be -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46dd08bd _UIGetCurrentFallbackTraitCollection + 962
5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46dce21a +[UITraitCollection _currentTraitCollection] + 196
6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff476366c6 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2386
7   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b030ef9 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 255
8   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b0358ff _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 517
9   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b041fe4 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 80
10  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2af8a4a8 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEd + 324
11  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2afbfab3 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 643
12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4715c27c _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 104
13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471fd878 __handleEventQueueInternal + 6902
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afbac1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afb9ec __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afb1c4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af5ecf __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af56b6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
19  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff3815cbb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47162a67 UIApplicationMain + 1621
21  Telegram                            0x000000010bcbb0f4 main + 132
22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5123bcf5 start + 1
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of old Telegram source code, TGSimpleImageView will cause this problem simply in traitCollection function put following code instead of 'return nil'

```
- (UITraitCollection *)traitCollection
{
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        [UITraitCollection setCurrentTraitCollection:[[UITraitCollection alloc]init]];
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    };
    return [[UITraitCollection alloc]init];
}
```

Comment: i am not using Telegram but getting same issue in my app. Please suggest how to identify this issue. Not able to understand which Library giving this issue

Comment: I read the stacktrace of error, for example if you take a look at stacktrace above, you can see that traitCollection is nil, so I searched for a place which is like it, I don't know maybe I've found it by luck -_-